# How to make the default width of of the left side wider

Tags: avalondock

I am trying to figure out how to make the default width of the left side wider. When I click on the tab to expand the left side it isn't wide enough to see the data in the pane.

```
<avalonDock:LayoutRoot.LeftSide>
                <avalonDock:LayoutAnchorSide>
                    <avalonDock:LayoutAnchorGroup>
                        <avalonDock:LayoutAnchorable Title="Document Properties">
                            <StackPanel Width="500">
                                <Grid>
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                                    <Label Grid.Row="0" Margin="0,10,0,0">File #</Label>
                                    <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Width="100" Height="20" Margin="0,10,0,0"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </avalonDock:LayoutAnchorable>
                    </avalonDock:LayoutAnchorGroup>
                </avalonDock:LayoutAnchorSide>
            </avalonDock:LayoutRoot.LeftSide>
```

Thanks for the help, 
Gary

Answer (score 1):

Add AutoHideWidth and FloatingWidth to your LayoutAnchorable tag:

```
<avalonDock:LayoutAnchorable Title="Document Properties"
                             AutoHideWidth="500"
                             FloatingWidth="500">
```

I used 500 pixels here, but you can set any width you like.

AutoHideWidth is the width when it pops out from its hidden state; FloatingWidth is the width when you drag it free from the side of the window.